# How do I implement a masked softmax cross-entropy loss function in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a softmax cross-entropy loss in Keras. The loss should only consider samples with labels 1 or 0 and ignore samples with labels -1 (i.e. missing labels). I found a `binary_crossentropy` function that does that but I couldn't implement a softmax version for it.

Here's the `binary_crossentropy`:

```
def binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(tf.multiply(y_pred, tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), tf.float32)),
                                    tf.multiply(y_true, tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), tf.float32))), axis=-1)
```

I tried to change the `K.binary_crossentropy()` function with `K.categorical_crossentropy`, but this only gives me "nan" when the loss is calculated.

How can I implement this on Keras (Tensorflow backend)?

---

#### Edit

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328604/3924118), the author suggested to use `sparse_crossentropy`, but I ran into an error while compiling the model:

Use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and `boolean_mask`

```
def sparse_crossentropy_masked(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    y_pred_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    return K.mean(K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true_masked, y_pred_masked))
```

#### Testcase

```
y_true = tf.constant(np.array([0.,1.,2., -1]))
y_pred = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.], [0.,0.,1.]]))
loss_op = sparse_crossentropy_masked(y, y_hat)

y_true_1 = tf.constant(np.array([0.,1.,2.]))
y_pred_1 = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.]]))
loss_1_op = sparse_crossentropy_masked(y_true_1, y_pred_1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    loss, loss_1 = sess.run([loss_op, loss_1_op])
    assert loss == loss_1



model.compile(loss=sparse_crossentropy_masked)
### TypeError: int returned non-int (type NoneType
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason ton keep this samples fed in the network ? Why not simply get rid of it in you train set ?

Comment: @ThibaultBacqueyrisses each sample is associated with 1 or more outputs. So if I remove them from training  I'm losing information for many labels.

Comment: @MarcosSantana, please update your question considering mujjiga's answer and error you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and `boolean_mask`

```
def sparse_crossentropy_masked(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    y_pred_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    return K.mean(K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true_masked, y_pred_masked))
```

#### Testcase

```
y_true = tf.constant(np.array([0.,1.,2., -1]))
y_pred = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.], [0.,0.,1.]]))
loss_op = sparse_crossentropy_masked(y, y_hat)

y_true_1 = tf.constant(np.array([0.,1.,2.]))
y_pred_1 = tf.constant(np.array([[1.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.]]))
loss_1_op = sparse_crossentropy_masked(y_true_1, y_pred_1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    loss, loss_1 = sess.run([loss_op, loss_1_op])
    assert loss == loss_1
```

---

#### Update

`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` seems to have a bug, see a similar issue [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4816). So we are left with using `categorical_crossentropy` instead, but now the ground truth should be converted into one-hot-encoding. We will represent the labels to be not considered using -1 (print the `y` in below code if you are confused)

Working example:

```
def categorical_crossentropy_masked(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, tf.reduce_any(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), 1))
    y_pred_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.reduce_any(tf.not_equal(y_true, -1), 1))
    return K.mean(K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_masked, y_pred_masked))

inputs = Input(shape=(3,))
outputs = Dense(32, activation='relu')(inputs) 
outputs = Dense(16, activation='relu')(outputs) 
outputs = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(outputs)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=[categorical_crossentropy_masked])

x = np.random.randn(100,3)
y = np.random.randint(0,3, size=(100))

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
# make some targets to -1 
y[np.random.randint(0,100, size=(15))] = np.ones((15,y.shape[-1]))*-1.

model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks @mujjiga but when I compiled the model with that function  got the following error: TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)